Power Automate - Get value of one column with multiple selections from array created by Get Items and add in select operator to view in shared email
In my flow, I need to get the value of a specific column (Field_2) for an item in a SharePoint list that is a choice selection with multiple selections.
First, I use Get Items with a filter query which gets to multiple items. This produces an array.
[
  {
    "Rig": "<a href=\"https://URL">CA</a>",
    "Well": "B47",
    "Start Date": "03 Sep 2024",
    "Update": null,
    "Progress": "<font color=\"gold\">Upcoming</font>",
    "Hole/Csg size": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 17,
        "Value": "20\""
      }
    ],
    "Services": null
  },
  {
    "Rig": "<a href=\"https://URL">CA</a>",
    "Well": "B47",
    "Start Date": "26 Sep 2024",
    "Update": null,
    "Progress": "<font color=\"gold\">Upcoming</font>",
    "Hole/Csg size": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
        "Id": 18,
        "Value": "13-3/8\""
      }
    ],
    "Services": null
  },
  

How can I get the value of "Hole/Csg size" column from the output of the Get Items? to be presentable in the email shared eventually getting the information from "Select" data operator?

below is the full flow

